# Making a call from one extension(100) to another extension(200) through ari-client (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, asterisk

Precise overview about the flow:

- I am calling my initial extension(100) using Zoiper through Twilio sip domain which actually direct the call to my asterisk server.
- Now when my call is in asterisk server I'm trying to forward it to another extension(200) using ari-client.
- For now I was trying to do it internally (attaching my code chunks)

**code from ari-client index.js**

```
dialedChannel = await client.channels.originate({
endpoint: "PJSIP/twilio0",
app: ariConfig.appName,
extension: "200",
});
```

**configuration from extension.conf for extension(200)**

```
[from-internal]
exten = 200,1,Answer()
same = n,Wait(1)
same = n,Playback(hello-world)
same = n,Hangup()
```

So can anyone guide me here. How it can be possibly done? or it is even possible using ari-client?

Thanks in advance

- Trying to forward my call to another extension from current extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either context/extension/priority OR application/appdata.
Not both at same moment.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-manager-api-action-originate/

You also should include the destination number in the endpoint.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-cmd-dial/